# Copying files with file locks in Java

Tags: java, file-copying, file-locking

I'm working on a Java process that should efficiently (and recursively) copy files/directories from a source location to a destination location.

To do this, I want to:

- create a lock
- if the destination file does not exist, copy it
- else if the destination file is different, copy it
- else they are the same, so do nothing
- release the lock

To check the contents are equal, I was planning on using the Apache Commons IO [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) method `contentsEqual(...)`. To do the copying, I was planning to use the Apache Commons IO [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) method `copyFile(...)`.

So, the code I came up with is (this is just for files, directories are handled recursively down to this method for files):

```
private static void checkAndUpdateFile(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
  FileChannel channel = out.getChannel();
  FileLock lock = channel.lock();

  if (!dest.exists()) {
    FileUtils.copyFile(src, out);
  } else if (!FileUtils.contentEquals(src, dest)) {
    FileUtils.copyFile(src, out);
  } 

  lock.release();
  channel.close();
  out.close();
}
```

This does the file locking (great), and copies the files (super).

However, whenever it copies the files, it sets the copied files' last modified timestamp to the time of the copy. This means that subsequent calls to [`FileUtils.contentEquals(src, dest)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#contentEquals%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) continue to return `false`, so the files are re-copied.

What I'd really like is similar to [`FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest, true)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29), which preserves the file timestamps - and does get true from calling `FileUtils.contentEquals(src, dest)`. That would require the lock to be on the `File`, not the `FileOutputStream`, as otherwise the call to `FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest, true)` fails and throws an Exception because the file is locked.

Alternatively, I considered doing what the `FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest, true)` method does, which is to call `dest.setLastModified(src.lastModified())`. However, this would have to be called after the lock is released, which could cause problems if the same process has been executed more than once simultaneously.

I had also considered the ides of putting the lock on the source file, but that doesn't help as I'd have to put it on a `FileInputStream`, and I want to pass a `File` to `FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest)`.

So:

1. Is there any easier way to achieve what I am trying to do?
2. Is it possible to put a lock on a File, rather than a derivative of File?
3. What would be the best way of resolving this?

   - i.e. do I just need to write my own approach method for part of this? (probably `copyFile(...)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... in the end, I went for the approach of writing my own `copy()` and `compare()` methods to use the `FileChannel` objects which have been locked. Below is the solution I came up with - although I expect others might be able to suggest improvements. This was informed by looking at the source code for apache.commons.io classes [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#line.76) and [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#line.84).

```
private static final int s_eof = -1;
private static final int s_byteBuffer = 10240;

private static void checkAndUpdateFile(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
  FileChannel srcChannel = in.getChannel();
  FileChannel destChannel = null;
  FileLock destLock = null;

  try {
    if (!dest.exists()) {
      final RandomAccessFile destFile = new RandomAccessFile(dest, "rw");
      destChannel = destFile.getChannel();
      destLock = destChannel.lock();
      copyFileChannels(srcChannel, destChannel);
      dest.setLastModified(src.lastModified());
    } else {
      final RandomAccessFile destFile = new RandomAccessFile(dest, "rw");
      destChannel = destFile.getChannel();
      destLock = destChannel.lock();
      if (!compareFileChannels(srcChannel, destChannel)) {
        copyFileChannels(srcChannel, destChannel);
        dest.setLastModified(src.lastModified());
      }
    }
  } finally {
    if (destLock != null) {
      destLock.release();
    }
    if (destChannel != null) {
      destChannel.close();
    }
    srcChannel.close();
    in.close();
  }
}

protected static void copyFileChannels(FileChannel src, 
                                       FileChannel dest) throws IOException {
  final long size = src.size();
  for (long pos = 0; pos < size; ) {
    long count = 
      ((size - pos) > s_byteBuffer) ? s_byteBuffer : (size - pos);
    pos += dest.transferFrom(src, pos, count);
  }
}

protected static boolean compareFileChannels(FileChannel a, 
                                             FileChannel b) throws IOException {
  if (a.size() != b.size()) {
    return false;
  } else {
    final ByteBuffer aBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(s_byteBuffer);
    final ByteBuffer bBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(s_byteBuffer);
    for (int aCh = a.read(aBuffer); s_eof != aCh; ) {
      int bCh = b.read(bBuffer);
      if (aCh != bCh || aBuffer.compareTo(bBuffer) != 0) {
        return false;
      }
      aBuffer.clear();
      aCh = a.read(aBuffer);
      bBuffer.clear();
    }
    return s_eof == b.read(bBuffer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Guava Google Core Library` to compare two files.

[As Byte Source](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Resources.html#asByteSource%28java.net.URL%29)

[ByteSource Doc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html#contentEquals%28com.google.common.io.ByteSource%29)

```
        ByteSource inByte = Resources.asByteSource(srcFileURL);
        ByteSource outByte = Files.asByteSource(srcFileURL2);
        boolean fileEquals= inByte.contentEquals(outByte));
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but how does that work with the file locking? I cannot get a `FileLock` on a `ByteSource`, I cannot create a ByteSource from a file whilst there's a separate lock and it wouldn't make sense to make the `ByteSource` outside of the lock - i.e. in terms of the problem, this is functionally equivalent to using `apache.commons.io.FileUtils`

Comment: @amaidment you can get URL from file http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURL%28%29 . Once you have lock on file get the URL and get input byte source and same for destination file

Comment: No, that doesn't work. When the code calls  `inByte.contentEquals(outByte)`, it is trying to access a file that has been locked, and fails with an "IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has a locked a portion of the file"

Comment: Also, as a general rule, it's not great practice to recommend people to use deprecated methods.